# Login en python usando listas de diccionarios

Tags: python

Estoy creando un programa en Python, el cual cuenta con dos tipos de menús dependiendo de como se ingrese, y para ingresar cree un login usando una lista de diccionarios con los datos de los administradores y con una cierta cantidad de intentos. Mi intención es la persona que use el login ingrese sus datos y que se muestre un mensaje que indique si se ingresaron bien o no los datos y permita acceder al menú correspondiente si se hizo bien, y mi problema es que cuando pruebo el login usando los datos de los últimos usuarios de la lista, me descuenta intentos y luego me da acceso. Es decir, es como si el login me descontara intentos al recorrer la lista de administradores, lo cual no está bien ya que primero debería recorrer toda la lista buscando los datos y después indicar si los datos están bien o no.

¿Cómo solucionar este problema?

```py
administradores=[{"EMAIL":"diego@yahoo.com","PASSWORD":"diego123"},{"EMAIL":"alberto@yahoo.com","PASSWORD":"alberto123"},{"EMAIL":"rodolfo@yahoo.com","PASSWORD":"rodolfo123"},{"EMAIL":"norma@yahoo.com","PASSWORD":"norma123"}]

    def login():
    print("""
    (1) Administrador
    (2) Usuario
    """)
    opcion=int(input("Por favor indique si ud es administrador o un usuario eligiendo la opcion correspondiente: "))
    reintentos=int()
    reintentos=0
    if opcion==1:
        while reintentos<5:
            email=str(input("Ingrese su email: "))
            contrasena=str(input("Ingrese su contraseña: "))
            for administrador in administradores:
                if email==administrador.get("EMAIL") and contrasena==administrador.get("PASSWORD"):
                    print("Se ha iniciado la sesion correctamente.")
                    return menu_admin()
                else:
                    reintentos+=1
                    print("El email o la contraseña no son correctos. Por favor verifiquelos e intentelo nuevamente.")
                    print(f"Te quedan {5-reintentos} intentos.")

    elif opcion==2:
        registro=str(input("Por favor escriba su nombre: "))
        print(f"Bienvenida/o {registro}! A continuacion veras un menu de opciones:")
        menu_cliente()

    else:
        print("Opcion incorrecta. Por favor intentelo nuevamente.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto ocurre porque tú has programado el aumento a la cuenta de reintentos en el else dentro del `for` dónde vas recorriendo la lista de administradores.

Date cuenta como si hay 10 administradores y por casualidad ingresaron el último, el código que está dentro del `for` se va a ejecutar 10 veces, de esas todas menos la última no cumplirían la condición del `if` y van a entrar al `else`, por lo que `reintentos` llegaría a un valor de 9, y el mensaje `El email o la contraseña no son...` también se va a imprimir 9 veces.

Y si no ingresaron un administrador válido, esto llegaría a 10 y `reintentos` saldría con el valor de 10 ya de ese ciclo, por lo que al evaluar la condición del ciclo exterior (el `where`) esta ya no se va a cumplir y ese ciclo también va a terminar.

No es lo que tu quieres y por tanto ese código debiera estar fuera del `for administrador in...`, solo dentro del `while`.

Dado que dentro del for haces un `return` y eso terminaría la función, no hace falta ni llevar algún control, solo con sacarlo del `for` bastaría, pues va a llegar a ese punto solo si nunca se cumplió la condición del `if`. Es decir, solo si no ingresaron el email de un administrador y su contraseña correctamente.

```
while reintentos<5:
    for administrador in administradores:
        if email==administrador.get("EMAIL") and contrasena==administrador.get("PASSWORD"):
            print("Se ha iniciado la sesion correctamente.")
            return menu_admin()
    
    reintentos+=1
    print("El email o la contraseña no son correctos. Por favor verifiquelos e intentelo nuevamente.")
    print(f"Te quedan {5-reintentos} intentos.")
```